# Can I bind multidimensional data to a DataGridView in C# and .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, datagridview, interface

I'm looking to develop an app which features worksheets subclassed from DataGridView. Users can paste (or import) CSV-like data into the worksheet and it will be reflected in a data structure in memory - my first guess would be a 2D array of floats.

DataGridView can be bound to objects with a certain set of interfaces (i.e. IList, IListSource etc.) and so, in theory I could create a class which encapsulates a 2D array and implements one of these interfaces. However, what is puzzling is that the interface specs seem to only cater for 1 dimensional arrays - see [IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx) for example. What is going on?!

**Update:** From the answers, seems IList caters for lists of objects. Is there a way then to bind a multi-dimensional array of arbitrary size (of floats) to a DataGridView? Or  is it ok to use the DataGridView itself as the data structure for storing the floats?

Answer (score 3):

I've done something like this before, [here](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/browse_thread/thread/ae1251a6855b9254/29ed401fdfb1b4c1#29ed401fdfb1b4c1) - representing a 2D array in an `IList`; might be useful.

Comment: It's a good idea but not quite there - I'm working with data that may resize in either dimension i.e. a column may be deleted just as readily as a row

Comment: That can in theory be simulated, but the grid control won't help you with it.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it this way. An IList can be a collection of objects. Each object can then have multiple properties within them. So essentially, that's like a 2D array. The first dimension is the object, and all of it's properties, and the second dimension, is a collection of said objects. Something like this:

```
list[0] --> Name, (think of this as list[0]["Name"])
            Age, (think of this as list[0]["Age"])
            Height  (think of this as list[0]["Height"])


list[1] --> Name, (think of this as list[1]["Name"])
            Age, (think of this as list[1]["Age"])
            Height  (think of this as list[1]["Height"])
```

So, in your case, if the columns are fixed then you just need to have one object that encapsulates all those fields and then have a collection of those objects that will then be bound to the DataGridView.

If this doesn't make any sense, then I didn't understand your question and I apologize.

Comment: Yup that makes sense, have modified question

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice [article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/BindArrayGrid.aspx) showing how to bind 2D arrays to a DataGridView.